# Change background image on hovering to a particular part of the current background image

Tags: html, css

I have 2 images. At the beginning there is one background image, but on hovering at a particular area on the image, I want to change the current background image into a new one. How to do that??
Currently the hover happens on the entire area of the image. How to specify particular dimensions of the image on which the hover should happen??

```css
.bground {
 width:100%;
 position:relative;
 background: url(../img/bg1.jpg) no-repeat top center;
 -webkit-transition-property: background;
 -webkit-transition-duration: 2s;

}

.bground:hover {
background: url(../img/bg2.jpg) no-repeat top center;
}
```

```html
<section id="bground" class="bground">
  <div class="display">
    <img src="img/logo.png" alt="Logo">
  </div>
  <div class="page-scroll">
    <a href="#about" class="btn btn-circle" style="color:#000000">
      <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down animated"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: And you don't mean dividing the section up into a grid of blocks that each have the `:hover` style?

Answer (score 0):

You can put hidden div(don't set its border or color anything) on the image where you want your hover effect.Set height and width as much you want and then set hover property to that div..Don't forget to make it's position absolute. it'll work..

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery `mouse-over` event on the image:

```
$('div.display img').mouseover(function(){
    // Specify the area here
    if ($(this).offset().left >= 50 && $(this).offset().top >= 50 && $(this).offset().left <=100 && $(this).offset().top <= 100) {
        $(this).css("background", "url(../img/bg2.jpg) no-repeat top center");
    } else {
        $(this).css("background", "url(../img/bg1.jpg) no-repeat top center");

    }
});
```